# Number items in order within Divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to number items in a list of divs using jQuery. Right now they are all hard-coded (item 1, Item 2, item 3...), but i want jQuery to number them as I will be reordering using jQuery UI's sortable plugin so I will need to re-order when items are shifted around.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="my-sortable my-sortable-active"> 
  <div class="my-content-block">
    <div class="my-sortable-header">Item 1: [Title Field] </div>
    <div class="my-sortable-body"> HELLO </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-content-block">
    <div class="my-sortable-header">Item 2: [Title Field] </div>
    <div class="my-sortable-body"> HI </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-content-block">
    <div class="my-sortable-header">Item 3: [Title Field] </div>
    <div class="my-sortable-body"> ANOTHER HELLO </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have this jQuery, but each item is numbered "Item 1", instead of 1, 2, 3, etc:

```
$('.my-sortable-active .my-sortable-header').each(function() {
    $('.my-sortable-active .my-sortable-header').prepend("<span>" + ($(this).index() +1) + "</span>");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [jQuery docu](http://api.jquery.com/each/) you get the index of an element directly from the `each()` callback, so use this:

```
$('.my-sortable-active .my-sortable-header').each(function( index ) {
    $(this).prepend("<span>" + (index +1) + "</span>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.my-sortable-active .my-sortable-header').each(function(index) {
    $(this).prepend("<span>" + ($(this).index() +1) + "</span>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.my-sortable-active .my-sortable-header').each(function(index) {
    $(this).prepend("<span>" + parseInt(index + 1) + " - </span>");
});
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/eMxwc/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CSS counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters) as well:

Example: http://codepen.io/splosch/pen/LdiGK

**HTML:**
Remove the "Item [counter]"

```
<div class="my-sortable my-sortable-active"> 
  <div class="my-content-block">
    <div class="my-sortable-header">[Title Field] </div>
    <div class="my-sortable-body"> HELLO </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-content-block">
    <div class="my-sortable-header">[Title Field] </div>
    <div class="my-sortable-body"> HI </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-content-block">
    <div class="my-sortable-header">[Title Field] </div>
    <div class="my-sortable-body"> ANOTHER HELLO </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.my-sortable {
  counter-reset: section;
}

.my-sortable-header:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Item " counter(section) ": ";
}
```

That way no extra javascript is needed, and the browser support is great ([caniuse.com --> CSS counters](http://caniuse.com/#search=counter))

Oh, and If youre listing things up please consider usage of `<ul>` or `<ol>` tags, they work fine in your case too.